# How to wait till an image has been rendered to the screen before calling next function on iPhone/Cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Is there away to wait till a CCSprite has actually rendered to the screen before proceeding? Or possibly a method with a callback to check when a sprite has completed rendering to the screen?

I can not use action sequences as all actions are suspended at the time of performing this task.

---

I am not explaining very clearly. I'll try a little better. I add an image to a layer, then call a method. But before the image has loaded and been rendered to the screen the method has already been called and finished.

```
CCSprite* aSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"anImage.png"];  
[aLayer addChild:aSprite z:1];

//need application to hold here till image is rendered;

[self aMethod];
```

Comment: you forgot to mention why you need to do this, what you want to achieve. I have a hunch there's a different (better) solution to the one you're asking about.

Comment: this is what I mean: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem You're fixated on a specific solution to an unknown-to-us problem or goal, but that may not actually solve what you try to achieve, or just not as well.

Comment: I understand what you are saying about XY problem and it is mostly true. Although I ask it in this fashion because I have had multiple issues where this type of solution would help. In this instance there may be several solutions but that would not contribute to the other array of situations. 
Either way here is what I am trying to achieve here...

Comment: ... In the game scene I have multiple layers that have moving objects and characters. When the player reaches a certain point everything freezes. This is done by pauseSchedulerAndActions on all children of the Game Scene. I am then adding a character to one of the layers. Once the character is rendered I am making a battle system on the HUD layer visible. but the Character is a large image file as it is a big boss and the HUD appears significantly before the boss.

Comment: Solution: load the boss and make it invisible until you're ready to display the HUD. You can also load the boss' texture using CCTextureCache async method and wait for it to complete. This is what I mean, there'll be a better (and easier) solution. If that doesn't quite solve the problem (I'm not sure I fully understand) I'm still certain you don't need what you were asking for but something else. ;)

Comment: I am ready based on when the image has loaded. So how can I determine when the image has loaded?

Comment: Pre-loading the texture at some point prior to this in your code, as LearnCocos2D mentioned, sounds like your best bet.

Comment: Also, are you sure that the few millisecond pause has an effect on user experience? Will they even notice? Is it worth "fixing"?

Comment: use addImageAsynch with target/selector or block to be notified once the texture has been loaded, see api ref: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/2.1/cocos2d-iphone/html/interface_c_c_texture_cache.html#a19844e2980e63b366605eaa97239ba59

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
-(void) draw {
    [super draw];
    [self doWhateverButDoItQuick];
}
```

This will be invoked after the specific draw of the sprite of interest, for each instance of that class. Whatever you do in there, if it takes too much time will tend to eventually drop your FPS.  Suppose you are currently running at 60FPS, and your complete cycle takes 12 ms, you have approximately 4 ms to complete that task without impacting the FPS. If you go overboard, your FPS will instantly drop to 30.

Comment: that timing thing is not at all limited to a single method like draw

Comment: true, but if there is one place where you can wreak havoc, that would be the ideal place ;)

Comment: not really, whether you spend 100ms in draw or update or just waiting for a background thread doesn't matter. Time spent is time spent. ;)

Comment: hmmm ... yes. that reticence of mine is a reflection of my 'personal' object modelling strategy. I tend to let graphics be completely free wheeling, and put all my control and view logic elsewhere (my code base :) ) where i can generally do something about a time 'hog'.

Comment: This method doesn't actually solve what I am asking. Perhaps I am not explaining very clearly. 
I add an image to a layer, then call a method. But before the image has loaded and been rendered to the screen the method has already been called and finished.  
`CCSprite* aSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"anImage.png"];
 [aLayer addChild:aSprite z:1];
//need application to hold here till image is rendered;
[self aMethod];`

Comment: that would be a bad idea in most circumstances, and i cant clearly see a way to accomplish this. It wont get rendered because you are pausing. I would then repeat Stefen's question : what are you trying to accomplish (ie why do you need this?).